# Return Active Directory jpegPhoto attribute in LDAP SQL query from SSMS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory, ssms, ldap-query

I've hit a brick wall on this issue and I can't seem to find or work out what is going wrong or find an answer to my problem ... I'm totally new to querying Active Directory, so I am hoping I've not done something that will warrant slapping my forehead when points me towards the solution!

So, I've uploaded images into both thumbnailPhoto and jpegPhoto and I can see in ADSI Edit that these do have a value.

I've set up a linked server (named ActiveDirectory) on our 2008 R2 Database Server and I can successfully query this and return results.  If I run the query below, it returns the values fine, but once I uncomment the jpegPhoto line (commented out in the code below), I get the error ...

> Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ActiveDirectory". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow.

The query runs correctly with jpegPhoto uncommented if the contents of that field are never populated in the returning result set.

```
SELECT
   objectGUID
   ,cn
   ,thumbnailPhoto
   --   ,jpegPhoto
FROM OpenQuery ( 
   ActiveDirectory,  
   'SELECT
      objectGUID
      ,cn
      ,thumbnailPhoto
      ,jpegPhoto
 FROM  ''LDAP://XXXXX/OU=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=XXXXX,DC=com''
 ') AS AD
WHERE cn = 'username'
```

It seems strange to me that the result can be returned from the OpenQuery (I've tried OpenRowset to no avail),  it fails outside of that it seems.

I have also tried all manner of CAST and CONVERT, but I'm at a loss now as to how I can actually get the contents of this field returned in my query (which I am just attempting to run in SQL Server Management Studio.

Has anyone come across this issue and overcome it?

I'm definitely hoping so!!

Thanks in advance!!

Gannon

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Old issue I know but for those finding this on the googles.

As far as I can tell, for thumbnailPhoto, OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Directory Services is limited to 4k field sizes. This means if you upload a teenytiny photo, it works.

For jpegPhoto, there is a difference in the field type -

thumbnailPhoto is single valued and has a upper-Range of 102400 bytes.

jpegPhoto on the other hand is multivalued and doesn’t enforce an upper-Range

And, according to other pages on the internet -

The ADSI provider for SQL Server is rather limited - not supporting multi-valued attributes is one of those limitations.